# Canvas Shadow DOM and Web Components

Tags: javascript, templates, dom, canvas, shadow

I am trying to make use of web components, templates and shadow DOM to create a canvas element. The problem is i cannot get the contex inside the prototype or I get this error when creating the shadow: HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'createShadowRoot' on 'Element': Author-created shadow roots are disabled for this element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<link rel="import" href="mycanvas.html">

</head>

<body>

<canvas is="my-canvas"></canvas>






</body>
</html>


<template id="mytemplate">
<style>
p {color:green;}
span {text-decoration: underline;}
canvas {background-color: #f00;
         width:300px;}
</style>

</template>
<script>

(function() {



     var myPrototype= Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
     var myDocument=document.currentScript.ownerDocument; 




     myPrototype.createdCallback=function() {
                                var shadow= this.createShadowRoot(); 
                                var template=myDocument.querySelector("#mytemplate");
                                var clone= document.importNode(template.content, true);

                                shadow.appendChild(clone);





                                            } //end prototype




     var myCanvas= document.registerElement('my-canvas', {

      prototype: myPrototype,
      extends:'canvas'

     });    
}());
</script>
```

Comment: What is `this` at `var shadow= this.createShadowRoot();`? `</html>` is before `<template>` element at `html`?

Comment: What is purpose of creating `shadowRoot` at `canvas` element?

Comment: even if i dont create the shadow i still can't get the contex.. Im new with web components so I am a bit confused @guest271314

Comment: What do you mean by _"still can't get the contex"_? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have a drawing function for a canvas but i want to implement it using web components, so when I try to var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d'), regardless of how I try to get the html canvas element ( with getElementsByTagName or anythig else) it says getContext is not a function @ guest271314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> regardless of how I try to get the html canvas element ( with
>   getElementsByTagName or anythig else) it says getContext is not a
>   function

Try substituting `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype` for `HTMLElement.prototype` when defining `myPrototype`